# Print special characters in interpolate

Tags: angularjs, jsp, interpolation

how can I print special characters using angularjs´s interpolate function (portuguease accents)?

```
{{product.name}} --> Não é um bom exemplo
```

Currently I´d get --> NÃ£o Ã© um bom exemplo

EDIT:

tried to create a simple plunkr but it just worked. Now I wonder if this has anything to do with a JSP.

The code is pretty simple, just a ng-controller basically

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Tried to add a simple angularjs one, but it just worked...

wonder if this has any relation to jsp instead of html now

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found it:

adding charset="utf-8" on each script import with special characters did the trick:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/scripts/client.js" />" charset="utf-8"></script>
```